# Google Maps API, Can you set a marker for an entire country?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

The title pretty much asked the question... but I'd like to use the Google Maps API to target countries, not specific addresses.

Is this possible?

Comment: I've been setting markers on cities by reverse geocoding a city name and the marker usually succesfully hits a "key place" in the city. I suggest you try it out on countries (remember to set a low-zoom)

Answer (score 0):

You could create an overlay over the country, with  polygons/circles/rectangles.

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#Rectangles